# Windows Server 2012 login too slow to appear

Tags: windows

on windows server 2012 the after I lock the desktop it can take ages to unlock and i.e. just for the login to appear again. Is this the norm?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the startup process is substantially slow when compared with windows 8 pro.

Then again, windows server includes so many more services and security measures that are initiated when beginning a new session so the delay makes sense.

I believe if you boot in safe mode or one of the other many options available in  the F8 menu. (Rapidly press F8 continuously during boot)  that some of the delay will be absolved.